# If $\Lambda_n \in B(X,X)$ and $f(\Lambda_n(x))$ is pointwise bounded for all $x$, and all $f \in X^* $then $\Lambda_n$ is uniformly bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a banach space. If $\Lambda_n$ are all bounded linear operators $X \to X$, and $f(\Lambda_n(x))$ is pointwise bounded for all $x$,  and all $f \in X^* $then $\Lambda_n$ is uniformly bounded

This problem clearly screams uniform boundedness principle. I am just not sure how to apply it. I have show that for each $f \in X^*$  $f(\Lambda_n)$ is uniformly bounded, by simply applying uniform boundedness on the linear operators $f(\Lambda_n)$. However, I dont know what to do from here. I feel like I need to pick a nice $f \in X^*$ so that I can somehow claim $||\Lambda_n||\leq ||f(\Lambda_n)||$ but I do not know how to do that. The problem is that I have upper bounds for linear operators but not lower bounds. I was also thinking of taking $x$ s.t $||x||<1$ and assuming towards contradiction that $||\Lambda_n(x)||\to \infty$ but that does not contradict $f$ bing bounded. Any hints would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

By UBP, it's enough to show that $\sup_n\|\Lambda_nx\|<\infty$ for all $x\in X$.  Indeed, let us fix $x\in X$ and let $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ denote its canonical image.  Note that
$$
\|\Lambda_nx\|=\sup_{f\in S_{X^*}}|f(\Lambda_nx)|=\sup_{f\in S_{X^*}}|(\Lambda_n^{**}x^{**})(f)|=\|\Lambda_n^{**}x^{**}\|
$$
Hence, again by UBP, it's enough to show that $\sup_n|f(\Lambda_nx)|=\sup_n|(\Lambda_n^{**}x^{**})(f)|<\infty$ for each $f\in X^*$.  But this is given.